# Simplest way to iterate through a Multiset in the order of element frequency?

Tags: java, guava, multiset

Consider this example which prints out some device type stats. ("DeviceType" is an enum with a dozenish values.)

```
Multiset<DeviceType> histogram = getDeviceStats();
for (DeviceType type : histogram.elementSet()) {
    System.out.println(type + ": " + histogram.count(type));
}
```

What's the simplest, most elegant way to print the distinct elements *in the order of their frequency* (most common type first)?

With a quick look at the [`Multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/2.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) interface, there's no ready-made method for this, and none of Guava's `Multiset` implementations (`HashMultiset`, `TreeMultiset`, etc) seem to automatically keep elements frequency-ordered either.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=356

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I just added this feature to Guava, see [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#copyHighestCountFirst-com.google.common.collect.Multiset-) for the Javadoc.

**Edit**: usage example of `Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst()` as per the original question:

```
Multiset<DeviceType> histogram = getDeviceStats();
for (DeviceType type : Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(histogram).elementSet()) {
    System.out.println(type + ": " + histogram.count(type));
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! So this will be included in Guava release 11 apparently?

Comment: Yep.  (I was the Guava intern this summer.)

It might get renamed, though; see http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=356.

Comment: I took the liberty to add a code example. Also marking this as accepted now. Thanks again for implementing the feature!

Comment: Well, pretty nice, but it would be better with ability to choose ascending/descending order of sorting.

Comment: I think I agree with @akapelko, I would have liked to see some more general purpose sort thing here.  On the other hand, its nice to have this when I google for "sort multiset guava" in an attempt to get my multiset histogram into descending order.  I am definitely pro-Guava.

Comment: I cannot find this feature in Guava 18 anymore ([GitHub issue #356](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/356)).

Comment: @Sonson123: I just tested with Guava 18.0 (the latest version), and [`copyHighestCountFirst()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#copyHighestCountFirst(com.google.common.collect.Multiset)) works just fine.

Comment: @Jonik, you are right - sorry for the confusion. (I may have used an older Guava version).

Answer (score 7):

Here's a method that returns a `List` of entries, sorted by frequency (**UPDATE**: used a flag to toggle ascending / descending order and used Guava's favorite toy: the `Enum Singleton Pattern`, as found in [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Item 3 ):

```
private enum EntryComp implements Comparator<Multiset.Entry<?>>{
    DESCENDING{
        @Override
        public int compare(final Entry<?> a, final Entry<?> b){
            return Ints.compare(b.getCount(), a.getCount());
        }
    },
    ASCENDING{
        @Override
        public int compare(final Entry<?> a, final Entry<?> b){
            return Ints.compare(a.getCount(), b.getCount());
        }
    },
}

public static <E> List<Entry<E>> getEntriesSortedByFrequency(
    final Multiset<E> ms, final boolean ascending){
    final List<Entry<E>> entryList = Lists.newArrayList(ms.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(entryList, ascending
        ? EntryComp.ASCENDING
        : EntryComp.DESCENDING);
    return entryList;
}
```

**Test code:**

```
final Multiset<String> ms =
    HashMultiset.create(Arrays.asList(
        "One",
        "Two", "Two",
        "Three", "Three", "Three",
        "Four", "Four", "Four", "Four"
    ));

System.out.println("ascending:");
for(final Entry<String> entry : getEntriesSortedByFrequency(ms, true)){
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0} ({1})",
        entry.getElement(), entry.getCount()));
}

System.out.println("descending:");
for(final Entry<String> entry : getEntriesSortedByFrequency(ms, false)){
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0} ({1})",
        entry.getElement(), entry.getCount()));
}
```

**Output:**

> ascending:
>   One (1)
>   Two (2)
>   Three (3)
>   Four (4)
>   descending:
>   Four (4)
>   Three (3)
>   Two (2)
>   One (1)

Comment: This is pretty nice, quite possibly the simplest way for now while Multiset itself doesn't provide it!

Comment: (Guava is so cool; I hadn't noticed e.g. the `Ints` class before. Looking at the API docs some more, `Files` was also new to me — a util collection similar to what Commons IO has, except with generics support & somehow *cleaner* overall.)

Answer (score 3):

**An Implementation using [ForwardingMultiSet](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMultiset.html) :**

*(**EntryComp** from [seanizer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342852/s-p-floyd-seanizer) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345633/simplest-way-to-iterate-through-a-multiset-in-the-order-of-element-frequency/4346245#4346245))*

```
enum EntryComp implements Comparator<Multiset.Entry<?>> {
    DESCENDING {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Entry<?> a, final Entry<?> b) {
            return Ints.compare(b.getCount(), a.getCount());
        }
    },
    ASCENDING {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Entry<?> a, final Entry<?> b) {
            return Ints.compare(a.getCount(), b.getCount());
        }
    },
}

public class FreqSortMultiSet<E> extends ForwardingMultiset<E> {
    Multiset<E> delegate;
    EntryComp comp;

    public FreqSortMultiSet(Multiset<E> delegate, boolean ascending) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        if (ascending)
            this.comp = EntryComp.ASCENDING;
        else
            this.comp = EntryComp.DESCENDING;
    }

    @Override
    protected Multiset<E> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<E>> entrySet() {
        TreeSet<Entry<E>> sortedEntrySet = new TreeSet<Entry<E>>(comp);
        sortedEntrySet.addAll(delegate.entrySet());
        return sortedEntrySet;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<E> elementSet() {
        Set<E> sortedEntrySet = new LinkedHashSet<E>();
        for (Entry<E> en : entrySet())
            sortedEntrySet.add(en.getElement());
        return sortedEntrySet;
    }

    public static <E> FreqSortMultiSet<E> create(boolean ascending) {
        return new FreqSortMultiSet<E>(HashMultiset.<E> create(), ascending);
    }

    /*
     * For Testing
     * public static void main(String[] args) {
        Multiset<String> s = FreqSortMultiSet.create(false);
        s.add("Hello");
        s.add("Hello");
        s.setCount("World", 3);
        s.setCount("Bye", 5);
        System.out.println(s.entrySet());
    }*/

}
```

Comment: +1. Elegant, in a way, to have a Multiset implementation which includes and abstracts away all the sorting logic. Client code using this would remain simple (no changes needed to example code in my question as long as FreqSortMultiSet was used). Drawback, of course, is having to write & maintain somewhat more code overall than in [S.P.Floyd's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345633/simplest-way-to-iterate-through-a-multiset-in-the-order-of-element-frequency/4346245#4346245)...

Answer (score 2):

Since [it is not yet implemented](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=356), I guess you can create a `Map` with key=type and value=count. Then sort that map - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)