# Arranging the elements of a list(with repeating elements) according to the frequency of occurrence

Tags: java, collections

What would be a good way to arrange the elements of a list(with repeating elements) according to the frequency of their occurrence in the list.

I need to use the top 5 frequently occurring items in the list.

I am thinking of using HashMap to count the elements' frequencies by incrementing the corresponding counter each time an element occurs & then doing HashMap iteration 5 times to find the highest freq. element over each iteration.

Answer (score 5):

How about this approach ?

maintain a map in that holds count

```
public static Map  <Foo,Integer>;
```

---

```
class Foo implements Comparator<Foo>{  
      private Bar element;


      public int compare(Foo f1, Foo f2){
       return SomeClass.map.get(f1) - SomeClass.map.get(f2);
      }

    }
```

just update map with update in `list`.

Wrap the access to List forcefully with the `addFooToList()` , `removeFooFromList()` and encapsulate the map updation logic there.

Comment: a) This will only work if the multiple objects are "the same", as opposed to "equal". b) it keeps the count inside the object that is counted. I'd call that bad design. A banana doesn't need to know how many bananas I have in the fridge

Comment: @Jigar OK, then you will have to update the frequency in all equal objects whenever you put or take one, which would increase complexity much more than needed

Comment: @Sean no if we use map (second approch) we won't have to. and also we can wrap `List` to some class which has `add/removeFooTo/FromList()`  which encapsulates the logic

Comment: @Jigar yes, if you remove the first approach, I'll upvote your answer :-)

Comment: @Jigar ok, you caught me there :-) +1

Comment: @Jigar but you know that you get that behaviour for free with a Guava Multiset / Multimap? :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [Guava `Multiset`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) and [order it by frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345633/simplest-way-to-iterate-through-a-multiset-in-the-order-of-element-frequency/4346245#4346245)

---

And about performance. Of course it depends on how many distinct values you have, but this test code took about a second on my machine. And I'd say that's reasonable enough for 10 M items:

```
Multiset<Integer> set = HashMultiset.create();
int amount = 10000000;
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    set.add(Integer.valueOf(random.nextInt(255)));
}
TreeSet<Entry<Integer>> sortedEntries = Sets.newTreeSet(
        new Comparator<Entry<Integer>>() {
    public int compare(Entry<Integer> a, Entry<Integer> b) {
        return Ints.compare(a.getCount(), b.getCount());
    }
});
Iterables.addAll(sortedEntries, set.entrySet());
for (Entry<Integer> entry : Iterables.limit(sortedEntries, 5)) {
    System.out.println(entry.getElement());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any comparison-based sorting will incur `O(N log N)` or worse time complexity, so (asymptotically) these are not good advices.

Your approach has `O(N)` time complexity, and that's the best you can get.  You can try to lower the constant (currently you're making roughly `6*N` accesses to elements of the list).

I would do it in two iterations like this: first count the frequencies using a HashMap.  Next, iterate over the entries in the map and keep an ordered 5-element array of the 5 most frequent values seen so far.  With each new element, check whether the value is more common than the 5th most common so far, and update the "Top 5" if necessary.

---

**UPDATE** A simpler solution, <s>of the same time complexity</s>.  First, calculate frequencies using [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).  Next, put all the entries into a [`PriorityQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) and pop five values.  The entries should be value-frequency pairs, comparable by frequency (as in @Jigar's solution).  Such an ordering will not be "consistent with equals" (see [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for explanation), but that's OK.

Comment: Sounds awfully complicated to me

Comment: @Sean If you're working with small lists, it's not worth to write complicated solutions.  But when you're working with big lists (say, 10M elements), you'll notice the difference in performance.

Comment: true, but the Guava Multisets I am suggesting are highly optimized data structures, and they are fast enough (see my added code)

Comment: @Sean OK, they may be fast enough (I've upvoted your answer), but as a part-time theoretical computer scientist I had to nitpick ;)

Comment: thanks, but what you have to realize is that the Guava guys are also hardcore CS geeks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would also use a HashMap. I found some code where I did just that:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

void increment(String s) {
    Integer oldCount = counts.get(s);
    if (oldCount == null) {
        counts.put(s, 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(s, oldCount + 1);
    }
}
```

Listing the elements:

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer>[] array = new Map.Entry[counts.size()];
counts.entrySet().toArray(array);
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> a, Map.Entry<String, Integer> b) {
        return b.getValue() - a.getValue();
    }
});
int x = 0, min = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> el : array) {
    String k = el.getKey();
    println("Count: " + el.getValue() + "\n" + k + "\n\n");
}
```