# Data Structure to cache most frequent elements

Tags: java, data-structures

Suppose I read a stream of integers. The same integer may appear more than once in the stream. Now I would like to keep a cache of N integers that appeared most frequently. The cache is sorted by the frequency of the stream elements.

How would you implement it in Java?

Comment: The interesting part to this is how to handle those numbers that are not in the currently in the top N cache. Is it a requirement to only store a fixed number of distinct integers from the stream in your cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Guava `Multiset`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) and [sort it by frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345633/simplest-way-to-iterate-through-a-multiset-in-the-order-of-element-frequency/4346245#4346245)

Comment: what if the stream does not fit in memory?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a binary indexed tree, the code in the link is for C++ and should be fairly straightforward to convert into Java (AFAICT the code would be the same):

[Paper Peter Fenwick](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aQhJLsivA13cJ%3aciteseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8917&rep=rep1&type=pdf%20frequency%20data%20structure&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiRzWNDDBOiPtweDzIjElRNwTt5nZ7_-xDH8kZ_flDyWrXlDUzmbO9kkXTHD-IPz53DfMvZ1ne2lnSgGft857RiUfV4SMYBAVT_cRZHnKuuHlY6VbN5h_UO4fj7599x1pHTOeDL&sig=AHIEtbRrN0vYGyeXO3Zy8EMZCmPF9WOcOg)

[Implementation in C++](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Fenwick_tree)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyData implements Comparable<MyData>{
  public int frequency = 0;
  public Integer data;
  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyData that) {
    return  this.frequency - that.frequency;
  }

}
```

Have it stored in a [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create an object model for the int, inside create a Count property.  Create a SortedVector collection extending the Vector collection.  Each time an integer occurs, add it to the vector  if it doesn't exist.  Else, find it, update the count property += 1, then call Collections.sort(this) within your Vector.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the range of the numbers? If so, it might make sense to use an array.  For example, if I knew that the range of the numbers was between 0 and 10, I would make an array of size 10.  Each element in this array would count the number of times I've seen a given number.  Then, you just have to remember the most frequently seen number.

e.g.

```
array[10];
freq_index = -1;
freq_count = -1;

readVal(int n){
  array[n]+=1;
  if array[n] > freq_count
    freq_index = n;
    freq_count = array[n];
}
```

Of course, this approach is bad if the distribution of numbers is sparse.

I'd try a priority queue.