# Regex to identify consecutive and non-consecutive duplicate words in multiline text

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a syntax checker (in Java) for a file that has the keywords and comma (separation)/semicolon (EOL) separated values. The amount of spaces between two complete constructions is unspecified.

**What is required:**

Find any duplicate words (consecutive and non-consecutive) in the multiline file.

```
// Example_1 (duplicate 'test'):
item1  , test, item3   ;
item4,item5;
test , item6;

// Example_2 (duplicate 'test'):
item1  , test, test   ;
item2,item3;
```

I've tried to apply the `(\w+)(s*\W\s*\w*)*\1` pattern, which doesn't catch duplicate properly.

Comment: Do you consider duplicates even if they are separated with multiple non-word characters? Like `word \n\t--- word`? Or should there only be strictly `[whitespace*][nonword][whitespace*]` between words that are checked for duplication?

Comment: By non-consecutive, do you mean `item1, item1` should not be matched?

Comment: @Alex See my updated answer that won't match if there are consecutive dupes

Comment: Suppose the string were `”a, a, a”`. Is only the first word to matched or are both the first and second words to be matched (much easier)?

Comment: @Cary Swoveland In the perfect case, I would like to match the first duplicate, because it will make the error handling (need to report the position of the first duplicate) much easier.

Comment: I don't think a regex is the right tool for this task. Instead, create a hash whose keys are unique words in the text and whose keys are the number of occurrences of the word in the text. Then select those keys in the hash whose values are greater than one.

Comment: ...as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282009/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-word), for example. (It's a one-liner in Ruby: `File.read(fname).split.tally.select { |_,v| v > 1 }.keys`).

Comment: So it is a dupe of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51190570/3832970) that deals with both consecutive and non-consecutive duplicate words.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew with all the respect, the OP's target is to find consecutive duplicates (which is quite frequent case), and searching one of the answers that accidentally covers something additional is like searching a needle in a haystack. Moreover, the thread doesn't work with multiline.

Comment: Multiline matching is a [solved issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression), too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use this regex with mode `DOTALL` (single line):

```
(?s)(\b\w+\b)(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h9Uogl/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?s)`: Enable `DOTALL` mode
- `(\b\w+\b)`: Match a complete word and capture it in group #1
- `(?=.*\b\1\b)`: Lookahead to assert that we have back-reference `\1` present somewhere ahead. `\b` is used to make sure we match exact same word again.

---

**Additionally:**

Based on earlier comments below if intent was to **not match consecutive word repeats like `item1 item1`**, then following regex may be used:

```
(?s)(\b\w+\b)(?!\W+\1\b)(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/h9Uogl/2)

There is one extra negative lookahead assertion here to make sure we don't match consecutive repeats.

- `(?!\W+\1\b)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match for consecutive repeats.

Comment: Doesn't this also catch consecutive duplicates?  I think it would need to be something like `(?s)(\b\w+\b)(?=.*\b\w+\b.*\b\1\b)` to fit the non-consecutive duplicates rule.

Comment: Do you mean `item1  item1` should not be matched?

Comment: That's my understanding from the non-consecutive specification in the question, but I'm not the OP. @J-Alex?

Comment: Yes, we need OP clarification because the above regex does not meet the "*I'm writing a syntax checker (in Java) for a file that has the keywords and comma (separation)/semicolon (EOL) separated values*" requirement as it may match across any amount of non-word chars.

Comment: Good catch, any duplicates shouldn't present at all, only unique phrases across all the text lines.

Comment: @J-Alex: So you want this regex to match `item1` if input is `item1 item1`?

Comment: @anubhava correct

Comment: Thanks Alex, in that case my original regex would work fine. I can remove `update` part from answer.

Comment: @anubhava I believe this would also be useful information to share. You can just edit it as an extra-case for further readers.

Comment: ok thanks Alex, that's a good suggestion (updated).

Comment: Your first regex matches no words in “a, a, a;”. Is that consistent with your understanding of the problem.

Comment: Regex-1 is what OP wanted and that one does match `a` twice in `a, a, a`

Comment: My apologies. I must have used your second regex.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
\b(\w+)\b(?:\s*[^\w\s]\s*\w+)+\s*[^\w\s]\s*\b\1\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ucqTXv/2)

**Details**

- `\b(\w+)\b` - Group 1: one or more word chars as a whole word
- `(?:\s*[^\w\s]\s*\w+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `[^\w\s]` - 1 char other than a word and whitespace char
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

  - `[^\w\s]` - 1 char other than a word and whitespace char
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\b\1\b` - the same value as in Group 1 as whole word.

To only match the word, put the second part of the regex into a positive lookahead:

```
\b(\w+)\b(?=(?:\s*[^\w\s]\s*\w+)+\s*[^\w\s]\s*\b\1\b)
         ^^^                                        ^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/alvCQw/2).

Java regex variable declaration:

```
String regex = "\\b(\\w+)\\b(?:\\s*[^\\w\\s]\\s*\\w+)+\\s*[^\\w\\s]\\s*\\b\\1\\b";
```

To make it fully Unicode aware add `(?U)`:

```
String regex = "(?U)\\b(\\w+)\\b(?:\\s*[^\\w\\s]\\s*\\w+)+\\s*[^\\w\\s]\\s*\\b\\1\\b";
```

Comment: If the string were “ item1  , test, item1, test, item1;”, only the first “item1” (not “test”) is matched with your first regex. Is that consistent with your understanding of the question?

Comment: @CarySwoveland OP needs validation. If there is a match, the string is invalid. Certainly it is in line.

Comment: What do you think about replacing [^\w\s] with [\W]?

Comment: Wiktor, but the OP's task is "Find any duplicate words...".

Comment: @J-Alex `\W` matches a space, too.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Then the https://regex101.com/r/alvCQw/2 (second regex in the answer) will do this.

Comment: Yes, impressive! I see you are avoiding consecutive matches. I expect that is because the question has been a moving target.