# How can I sort a Guava Multiset on entry value and count?

Tags: java, sorting, guava, multiset

I have a Guava `Multiset<Integer>` and would like to iterate independently through entries sorted on (a) element value and (b) element count. I have used [Simplest way to iterate through a Multiset in the order of element frequency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345633/simplest-way-to-iterate-through-a-multiset-in-the-order-of-element-frequency) as

```
ImmutableMultiset<Integer> entryList = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myIntegerMultiset);
for (Integer i : entryList) {
    System.out.println("I"+i);
}
```

but this returns all entries, whereas I would like a sorted list of `Multiset.Entry<Integer>` (one per unique value) which would allow me to get the count.

Independently I would like to get the same list of `Multiset.Entry<Integer>` sorted by the value of `<Integer>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Iterable<Multiset.Entry<Integer>> entriesSortedByCount = 
   Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(multiset).entrySet();
Iterable<Multiset.Entry<Integer>> entriesSortedByValue =
   ImmutableSortedMultiset.copyOf(multiset).entrySet();
```

Basically, you just need the `entrySet()`, instead of iterating over the `Multiset` itself.

Comment: You're making a SortedMultiset copy of the original multiset, which sorts elements by their value, and then getting the entrySet from that.  Is that what you were confused about?

Comment: I think it's clear now - the copying operation is the way of constructing an ImmutableSortedMultiset which presumably doesn't have a public constructor. And the act of creation initiates a sort automatically.

Comment: Correct.  It's like a `TreeSet`, where the `new TreeSet<E>(collection)` automatically creates a sorted `TreeSet` copy of the collection, except with a more descriptive name including the word "copy."

Comment: From the javadoc comments it looks like the order of elementSet() for the  `copyHighestCountFirst()` map is an implementation detail which might go away any time. `copyHighestCountFirst` only guarantees the `iterator()` order, not `entrySet()` order. From `Multiset#entrySet()` javadoc: `...The order of the elements in the element set is unspecified.`

Comment: From the ImmutableCollection Javadocs: "Deterministic iteration. The iteration order is always well-defined, depending on how the collection was created (see the appropriate factory method for details). View collections such as Multiset.elementSet() iterate in the same order as the parent, except as noted."

Answer (score 2):

You could get a set of entries and then sort it however you need.

Here is how you get a set of entries:

```
Set<Multiset.Entry<Integer>> entries = myIntegerMultiset.entrySet();
```

And then to sort we can define two comparators:

```
Comparator<Multiset.Entry<Integer>> byCount = new Comparator<Multiset.Entry<Integer>>() {
    int compare(Multiset.Entry<Integer> e1, Multiset.Entry<Integer> e2) {
        return e2.getCount() - e1.getCount();
    }
}

Comparator<Multiset.Entry<Integer>> byValue = new Comparator<Multiset.Entry<Integer>>() {
    int compare(Multiset.Entry<Integer> e1, Multiset.Entry<Integer> e2) {
        return e2.getElement() - e1.getElement();
    }
}
```

Then you can provide the comparators to a tree set to get a sorted collection:

```
Set<Multiset.Entry<Integer>> entries = myIntegerMultiset.entrySet();
Set<Multiset.Entry<Integer>> entriesSortedByCount = Sets.newTreeset(byCount);
entriesSortedByCount.addAll(entries);
Set<Multiset.Entry<Integer>> entriesSortedByValue = Sets.newTreeset(byValue);
entriesSortedByValue.addAll(entries);
```

Actually, Louis Wasserman's answer is much better, but I will post this one too in case you wanted to customize your sorting.

Comment: The second comparator is dangerous -- if the `Integer` values can be positive and negative, overflow can result in incorrect comparisons.  Prefer `Ints.compare(int, int)`, or `Integer.compare`, if you're on Java 7.  (It's okay in the first case, since subtracting nonnegative values can never overflow, but it's worth being wary.)

Comment: +1 since it's useful to know the Comparator approach (and to know the dangers).

Comment: + 1 since I was stuck in an environment where I could access only Guava 13, which does not have the `copyHighestCountFirst()` method.