# which data structure to chose Guava library

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity, guava

Here's my problem i have two data structure one : `countMark = new HashMap<Pair<String, String>, Integer>();` and the other which is the inverse `orderMark = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Pair<String, String>>>();`. I use the second one the quickly find the maximum value and the select a pair according to some rules.

But in my code i need to use `orderMark.containsKey(counter)` and that's not very efficient. As i increment the counter i also need to delete the specific pair. In consequence i have to do this `orderMark.get(count - 1).remove(key);`.

My question is i find that i could use MultiSet and MultiMap from Guava library but i didn't find the complexity about this data structure for add, contains, remove and get. And i would need a sorted map in order to select the pair which has the maximum value.

I hope that was sufficiently clear and thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I just found this link : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345633/simplest-way-to-iterate-through-a-multiset-in-the-order-of-element-frequency). I think i maybe could use only one multi set and use the `Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst()` in order to get the highest value but is it efficient or i should keep two seperate datastructure?

Comment: How often do you need to pull out the maximum value?  Also, you should _not_ be using `Pair`; you should write your own class that actually gives meaning to the fields.  (AutoValue, also from the Guava folks, might help with that.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The class Pair is a class that i wrote myself. I need to take the highest value quite a lot of time. It depends but it's planned to take few thousand times.

Comment: Then you should probably just keep track of the "current max" and update that every time you update the multiset; trying to track the reverse mapping is not likely to pay for itself.

Comment: Ok thank you i'll check that